# Limiting number of simultaneous connections system-wide?

Tags: networking, fedora, firewall, networkmanager

In my dormintory, I've got a not-so-nice networking environment, in which I'm identified only by mac-address of my ethernet card. In said environments, some limits of simultaneous opened connections apply, and if I open more connections than system allows, I end up getting blocked from network access for ~1 hr. This of course is the Thing that I don't enjoy at all.

On the other hand, I spend some time in other buildings, where I use wifi and no such limitations would make sense in there.

How can I automate the limiting/unlimiting connections number with the help of NetworkManager? 
Thanks.